# $\frac{1}{r^2}$ potentials in a Hamiltonian, standard ODE's.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, differential-operators

I have encountered this operator:

$$H := \nabla^2 + \alpha \frac{1}{r^2} $$

with $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. Surely, the eigenfunctions are some unique functions defined by the equation $$H \psi = E \psi$$ just like with the Airy equation. I wasn't able to find anything online (mostly because I don't know the name of the equation) so I'd appreciate someone pointing me the right way.

Background on the problem:

The Zeeman interaction of a magnetic monopole reads $\mathcal{H_Z} = \beta r^{-3} \vec{r} \cdot \vec{\sigma}$ where $\vec{\sigma}$ is a vector of Pauli matrices. Encomporating the spin related constants into $\beta$ gives us $\alpha$ and adding kinetic energy results in $\nabla^2$.

Comment: I might be wrong and this might not work, but did you try to write the laplacean in spherical coordinates and then use separation of variables. That is if you want to solve for the solutions. If not, make it more clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in Landau and Lifshitz, there is a problem there, known as the motion of a particle in the potential diverging as $1/r^{2}$ near the origin, they solve it there exactly. In fact the solution is the same as just for a free 3D particle in spherical coordinates, as you will get the $l(l+1)/r^{2}$ term from the spherical harmonics, you can define $l(l+1)+\alpha=\beta(l)(\beta(l)+1)$, thus, the most general solution will be like
$$\Psi(r, \theta, \varphi)=\int{dk}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}c_{lm}(k)j_{\beta(l)}(kr)Y_{l}^{m}(\theta, \varphi)$$
Where $j_{\beta(l)}(kr)$ is the spherical bessel function of the first kind and $Y_{l}^{m}(\theta, \varphi)$ is the spherical harmonics.

Comment: Which volume should I look in?

Comment: Vol III Quantum Mechanics, of course)